# Objective-c implement and call method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried to reproduce an example from this question:

[How to create a method in Objective-C that takes a NSString stringWithFormat as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396921/how-to-create-a-method-in-objective-c-that-takes-a-nsstring-stringwithformat-as)

And I have created in @interface:

```
- (float)strToFloat:(NSString *)str;
```

And in @implementation:

```
- (float)strToFloat:(NSString *)str {

    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                         withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@","
                                         withString:@"."];
    return [str floatValue];
}
```

After all when I try to compile the app I receive this error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'strToFloat'` in this method:

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"float value is: %.2f", [strToFloat labelPrice.text]);
}
```

What's wrong with this example?

Comment: You should really go back reading a basic Objective-C tutorial.

Comment: I'm still reading and I lost a couple of hours alone before trying to ask this question, which is now so obvious - but who is starting in a new language will pass for the same difficulties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call the method correctly:

```
NSLog(@"float value is: %.2f", [self strToFloat:labelPrice.text]);
```

I'm assuming your `addItem:` and `strToFloat:` methods are in the same class.

BTW - there are MUCH better ways to convert decimal string values to numbers that deal with a user's locale. Make use of `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: That's it. I'm new with objective-c and this syntax means exoteric to me, thanks!